# MVC5: Iterate ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my viewmodel, along with some other properties, I have this:

```
public int AuthorStatus {get; set;}

public string AuthorStatusLabelClass
{
    get
    {
        switch (AuthorStatus)
        {
            case 1:
                return "label-success";
            case 0:
                return "label-danger";
            case 2:
                return "label-warning";
            default:
                return "label-default";
        }
    }
    set
    {

    }
}

public IQueryable<VM_Authors> AuthorList { get; set; }
```

How can I access the AuthorStatusLabelClass in my controller;

```
    var vm = new ViewModels.VM_Authors();
    vm.Categories = new SelectList(db.AuthorCategories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
    vm.AuthorList = (from a in db.Authors
                     select new ViewModels.VM_Authors
                     {
                         FirstName = a.FirstName,
                         LastName = a.LastName,
                         Email = a.Email,
                         AuthorStatusLabelClass = ####HOW_SHOULD_I_RETRIEVE_IT_HERE####
```

So that I can use it in my view like this:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.AuthorList)
        {
        <tr>
            <td><span class="label @item.AuthorStatusLabelClass">@item.AuthorStatus</span></td>
            <td><img src="" class="img-circle" /></td>
            <td><span class="text-semibold">@item.FirstName @item.LastName</span></td>
            <td>@item.SelectedCategoryID</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        }
```

May be my whole approach is different? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Since you mention that `AuthorStatusLabelClass` is not one of your database's table's column *and* that it entirely depends on your `AuthorStatus`, then you *do not need* to assign it at all. Simply do:

```
select new ViewModels.VM_Authors
 {
     FirstName = a.FirstName,
     LastName = a.LastName,
     Email = a.Email,
     AuthorStatus = a.AuthorStatus //assign this
```

And when you get your `AuthorStatusLabelClass` in your `View`, just get it directly and your assigned `AuthorStatus` above will take care of the return of your `AuthorStatusLabelClass` in the `View`.

**Original:**

You do not seem to set a `setter` in your `AuthorStatusLabelClass`, thus you cannot do this:

```
select new ViewModels.VM_Authors
 {
     FirstName = a.FirstName,
     LastName = a.LastName,
     Email = a.Email,
     AuthorStatusLabelClass = //This is a set ####HOW_SHOULD_I_RETRIEVE_IT_HERE####
```

`AuthorStatusLabelClass` with `setter` may look like this:

```
private string _authorStatusLabelClass = "";
public string AuthorStatusLabelClass
{
    get
    {
        switch (AuthorStatus)
        {
            case 1:
                _authorStatusLabelClass = "label-success";
            case 0:
                _authorStatusLabelClass = "label-danger";
            case 2:
                _authorStatusLabelClass = "label-warning";
            default:
                _authorStatusLabelClass = "label-default";
        }
        return _authorStatusLabelClass;
    }
    set
    {
        _authorStatusLabelClass = value;
    }
}
```

Also, since you require your `AuthorStatus` to be set to a number first before you could retrieve your `AuthorStatusLabelClass`, you probably cannot really get your `AuthorStatusLabelClass` correctly without getting `AuthorStatus`. What you probably need in the class `AuthorStatusLabelClass` is an `indexer`:

```
public AuthorStatusLabelClass this[int index] { //thus you could give index as an input for this instance
  get {
    switch (index)
    {
        case 1:
            return "label-success";
        case 0:
            return "label-danger";
        case 2:
            return "label-warning";
        default:
            return "label-default";
    }
  }       
}
```

And use it like this:

```
vm.AuthorList = (from a in db.Authors
                 select new ViewModels.VM_Authors
                 {
                     FirstName = a.FirstName,
                     LastName = a.LastName,
                     Email = a.Email,
                     AuthorStatusLabelClass = a.AuthorStatusLabelClass[a.AuthorStatus]
```

Comment: a refers to the DB and I cannot refer to it as a.AuthorStatusLabelClass as there is no column in the db as AuthorStatusLabelClass

Comment: @KemalEmin I see, what do you have in the DB to produce the labelclass? Only the `a.AuthorStatus`?

Comment: Yes, AuthorStatus is either 0, 1 or 2.. so there is no point of having a varchar datatype.

Comment: @KemalEmin OK, in that case, because there is no direct translation between the `DB` columns to your `Model`, perhaps you may want to consider using `Dictionary` to translate between 0, 1, 2 to the `label-class` instead of using `AuthorStatusLabelClass` `get`. You could simplify your `AuthorStatusLabelClass` `get` by returning `_authorStatusLabelClass` and creates dictionary in your `Controller` which maps 0, 1, 2 to `label-class`

Comment: @KemalEmin no! Actually there is **a lot simpler** way to do that! You do **not** need to assign you `AuthorStatusLabelClass` at all! Simply assign your `AuthorStatus` will do!

Comment: I am coming from a WebForms background and if this was a repeater control, I would have a function that would take the value of AuthorStatus as a parameter and call that function in the Repeater's OnDataBound event... So, I can no problem get this done in the View and also quite easily in the Controller. However, many articles suggests the use of ViewModels for these kind of logic and I am kind of stuck between M, V and C...

Comment: What do you mean with your last comment?

Comment: @KemalEmin I mean, you do not need to assign your `AuthorStatusLabelClass` at all like what you do in you code. Just assign the `AuthorStatus` and in your `View`, simply get the `AuthorStatusLabelClass` because your assigned `AuthorStatus` will already take care of what will be returned by `AuthorStatusLabelClass`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `AuthorStatusLabelClass` has getter and an empty setter. Getter is dependent on `AuthorStatus` property. All you have to do is to set up `AuthorStatus` property properly.

```
select new ViewModels.VM_Authors
 {
     FirstName = a.FirstName,
     LastName = a.LastName,
     Email = a.Email,
     AuthorStatus = ### SETUP status and don't worry about AuthorStatusLabelClass ###
```

Comment: Hmm, the whole purpose I was trying to to it in ViewModel is because some people suggested this type of logic should be implemented in the ViewModel itself and the View should be as "thin" as possible.

Comment: @Kemal Emin, maybe they are right. viewModel has to deal with view-related logic. I'll remove the suggestion.